# Integrate javascript var value into redirect

Tags: javascript

From a php script I'm returning 3 values : all are transitioning over without any difficulty.

```
if(data.code == 600){
                            var PNRRef = data.locator;
                            var Lname = data.lname;
```

What I am trying to do is use these two var values in my redirect link and can't seem to figure it out :

```
window.location.href = '/US/en/local/res/MyReservation.php?PNRRef="PNRRef"&Lname="Lname"';
```

But it's not outputting correctly... Would anyone have a tip about how to integrate these ?

Thanks!

Comment: because you are not doing string concatenation, Those " quotes are doing nothing.

Comment: take care of the variables encoding when replaced in the uri, check below, this saved me a lot of time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need either to concatenate:**

```
window.location.href = '/US/en/local/res/MyReservation.php?PNRRef=' + PNRRef + '&Lname=' + Lname;
```

**or use Template literals (also called String interpolation)**

```
window.location.href = `/US/en/local/res/MyReservation.php?PNRRef=${PNRRef}&Lname=${Lname}`;
```

Those variables need to be encoded (`encodeURIComponent(...)`) before to make any request like ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = `/US/en/local/res/MyReservation.php?PNRRef=${PNRRef}&Lname=${Lname}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably template literals can be the solution for your issue.Instead of this:

```
window.location.href = '/US/en/local/res/MyReservation.php?PNRRef="PNRRef"&Lname="Lname"';
```

Use this:

```
window.location.href = `/US/en/local/res/MyReservation.php?PNRRef=${PNRRef}&Lname=${Lname}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a simpler solution (string concatenation) that always works

```
window.location.href = '/US/en/local/res/MyReservation.php?PNRRef='+encodeURIComponent(PNRRef)+'&Lname='+encodeURIComponent(Lname);
```

If you want to use a better URI encoding compliant to RFC3986 please use `rfc3986EncodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURIComponent`:

```
function rfc3986EncodeURIComponent (str) {  
   return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, escape);  
}
```